# Issue in getting custom header in Safari

Tags: web-services, http, cors

I have a webservice which is hosted on api server and application on app server which have url's like https://webservice.test.com/ for webservice server and https://app.test.com/ for application.

In application we get live data from database using several service we developed on webservice server using CORS http request.

In some service like login we have passed custom header x-auth-token from server.

[image]

Above is the screen shot of response we have got in Google Chrome for the request. The Custom header shown in last is available in application when we use it in chrome or Mozilla. The same response we got in Safari too, x-auth-token also available in response when we check in headers but can't able to read it through code.

Comment: I have similar issue. Please help if somebody know the solution for such problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of search i got answer for my problem, Custom headers from CORS http request can be read only in Safari for latest webkit version i.e above 537. I have checked in all safari browser which is above this webkit version will provide me cusom header value. And similarly in chrome if webkit is less than 537 version you can't able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer on github could helpa bit  : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6254